# Python Selenium cant find loadmore (mehr anzeigen) button

Tags: python, html, selenium

i basically want to click every load more button thats on the page before running the rest of my code because otherwise i wont be able to access each profile.

There are 2 Problems:

first how do i even access it? i tried similar methods to the fancyCompLabel part of my code but it wont work.

second im not sure how i should loop through all buttons since i would assume the second button only starts loading until the first one is clicked.

heres the relevant html part and a picture of the button

```
<span type="button" class="md-text-button button-orange-white" onclick="loadFollowing();">mehr anzeigen</span>
```

[image]

Heres the code to access each profile but as you can see it only runs until the first load button.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

time.sleep(3)

# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)

# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
#wd.switch_to.default_content()  # you do not need to switch to default content because iframe is closed already
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))

results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".fancyCompLabel")

for profil in results:
   print(profil.text) #heres the rest of my code but its not relevant 

wd.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see the second pop-up element located by `.hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll` is initially appearing out of the visible screen.
So after switching to the `iframe` you need to scroll to that element before trying to click on it.
Also, `presence_of_all_elements_located` doesn't actually wait for all the elements presence. It even doesn't know how many such elements will be. It returns once it finds at least 1 element matching the passed locator.
So I'd advice to add a short sleep after that line to allow all those elements to be actually loaded.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
actions = ActionChains(wd)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))

second_pop_up = wd.find_element_by_css(".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll")
actions.move_to_element(second_pop_up).build().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
second_pop_up.click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))
time.sleep(0.5)

for profil in results:
   print(profil.text) #heres the rest of my code but its not relevant 

wd.close()
```